# How to pass Model as parameters to the Wire (Livewire Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In the button, I can't pass Model product as parameters to the Wire (Livewire Laravel).

I have two function  initiateEdit first in model stockin and the other in model product.
in this code only call the function that found in the stockin model but i want the function in the product model.
how to call the function for the specific model ?

```html
<button
    class="flex items-center p-2 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-center text-white transition-colors duration-150 bg-gray-600 border border-transparent rounded-lg active:bg-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-gray"
    wire:click="$emit('initiateEdit', {{ $product['id'] }} )" 
    title="{{ __('Edit') }}">

    <x-heroicon-o-pencil class="w-5 h-5" />
    {{ $slot ?? '' }}
</button>
```

```php
public function initiateEdit($id)
{
    dd($id);
    $this->selectedModel = $this->model::find($id);
}
```

Comment: Do you have data for your `$this->model` in the component?

Comment: Yes i have, but the issue in the button i cannot select the model product.

Comment: have you listen this event in livewire component     protected $listeners = ['initiateEdit' => 'initiateEdit'];

Comment: This method does not solve my problem

Comment: Bhargav Rangani

Comment: The code you provided here should work, given that you listen for that event -- if you are listening for that event, then you'll need to provide more info before we can help with this.